# SQL: 1292 Truncated incorrect DOUBLE value: 'https://twitter.com/'

Tags: php, sql, doctrine, mariadb, mysql-error-1292

I am having really short query for MariaDB to fix broken links to twitter.

Table users has link_twitter as VARCHAR(255), to generate DB schema we are using PHP Doctrine, but I want to run this query manually.

The server is running MariaDB 1.10

The query:

```
UPDATE
    `user` AS u
SET
    u.link_twitter = "https://twitter.com/" + u.link_twitter
WHERE
    u.link_twitter NOT LIKE 'https://twitter.com/%';
```

But I am getting the 'Query Error:  (1292): Truncated incorrect DOUBLE value: 'https://twitter.com/' '

I know, that this question was asked a lot in the past but none of the solutions worked for me. :-(

Please, how can I fix it?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the proper string concatenation method:

```
UPDATE user u
    SET u.link_twitter = CONCAT('https://twitter.com/', u.link_twitter)
    WHERE u.link_twitter NOT LIKE 'https://twitter.com/%';
```

`+` means addition in MariaDB/MySQL (and most databases).  Hence it tries to treat its arguments as numbers.

Comment: Thank you, I feel so dumb. but sometimes the simplest mistakes are the hardest ones to fix. :D

Comment: @VojtaMareš, actually some databases use `+` for concatenation.